# Why does React pre-populate input tags with the last keyboard input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a list of input tags wrapped in a div to produce an editable text list.

However, when I add a new element to this list by hitting Enter, the new empty element is automatically populated with the last keyboard input, instead of being blank.

Here is a link the JsBin describing the issue:

https://jsbin.com/kovipurace/edit?html,output

I am expecting an empty input instead.

Is there a way to implement the expected behaviour correctly?

I initially based my code off of the CommentForm in the react tutorial, but I have deliberately not used a form tag to give cleaner use of the hitting the Enter key (don't want to mess around with e.preventDefault() etc.) I have also put in additional functionality in the actual version to allow updating existing values using an onBlur event.

**What I have tried:**

I have (*correctly, hopefully!*) implemented controlled components as stated in the docs.

I have experimented with using defaultValue and instead of value but the effect is the same. In both cases I am using {this.props.value}

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. There is only a single `TextEntry` element. When React rerenders, it reuses that component. React renders the value of `this.state.value`. You are not setting the value to an empty string anywhere. If you set it to an empty string, the input will be empty.

Comment: TextEntry sets its initial state from it's props. This is how previous text entries show.

I tried explicitly set the value of the lone text element before. I have added that back in to the example. It's value still gets overridden by keyboard input. Please see the updated JsBin

Answer (score 0):

You create new textentries with textEntry text.

```
keyHasBeenPressed : function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      var textEntry = this.refs.textEntry.value;
      this.props.createEntry(textEntry);
    }      
},
```

All you need is to make the args of createEntry blank.

```
this.props.createEntry();
```

https://jsbin.com/daqura/1/edit?html,output

Comment: That prevents anything being appended to the parent's props. In your example the previously entered text values are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I found help on #reactjs IRC channel and commenters here.

In the keyHasBeenPressed function, the state needs to be set explicitly again, as it is in handleChange.

getInitialState is just used to intialize state **once** in a component's life cycle.

Comment: The code only works accidentally because you are mistakenly using `event.target.value`, instead of `e.target.value`. What you really need is `this.setState({value: ''})`, and that's exactly what I meant in my comment: you are never setting the value to empty, so it will never become empty. After pressing enter you have to explicitly reset the value. `setState` does not unmount the component, it updates the state and rerenders the component.

Comment: Thanks Felix, I was unaware of the concept of component **reuse**. I was expecting get initial state to reset the value each time, hence trying to use an empty value props (I'm since aware of the anti-pattern). I'm assuming that getInitialState for that lone TextEntry is only actually called once?

Comment: Exactly! Component reuse is actually pretty important, otherwise a component would loose its state if something higher in the tree rerenders. That's also exactly what makes React fast: Components can specify when they should be rerendered to avoid unnecessary rerenders. But that only works if a component is reused.